# Binding a html content in scope variable without using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to bind html content using scope variable (without using ng-bind-html-unsafe) in angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="dataController">{{test}}</div>

$scope.test = "<div>Html content</div>"
```

Comment: what is the problem if you use?

Comment: according to my project guidelines ng-bind should not be used, is there any other way? http://jsbin.com/kuwovoxa/1/edit

Comment: according to your project guidelines then scope variables shouldnt contain html meant to be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fe9TA/)

```
function dataController($scope,$sce){
   $scope.test = "<div>Html content</div>";
   $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.test);
}
```

View

```
<div ng-bind-html="test"></div>
```